# Adding all elements together in a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say, if there is an input matrix whose dimension N is unknown (it could be 2D, 3D, or some D.) to the receiving end:

```
import tensorflow as tf
m = tf.keras.backend.random_normal([2, 3,4], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1) # a 3D matrix
```

or

```
m = tf.keras.backend.random_normal([3], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1) # a 1D matrix
```

or

```
m = tf.keras.backend.random_normal([3,7], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1). # a 2D matrix
```

On the receiving end, I need to add all the elements in the matrix. How do I do that?

I was thinking of some sort of for loop

```
for n in N # N is the dimension of the matrix
 sum = tf.reduce_sum(m, axis=-1)
```

I am not sure how to get `N` on the receiving end, or should it be done differently? In MATLAB, it'd be like

```
sum_of_a_m = sum(m(:));
```

Thanks a lot. A couple of lines code is highly appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried `sum(m)`?

Comment: Try Numpy. Use numpy.matrix.sum() method.

Comment: @RudrThakur If I prefer not to change the format/data type of the data?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Seems does not sum all the elements as the title specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

m = tf.keras.backend.random_normal([3], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1)
ma = tf.keras.backend.eval(m)

sum_elements = ma.sum()

print(sum_elements)
```